# Closed form for $\sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k}{n} (H_n-H_k) x^k$

Tags: summation, logarithms, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

The sum originated from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3297799/269624) and I found (experimentally) two closed form cases:

$$\sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k}{n} (H_n-H_k)=(-1)^{n+1} H_n$$

$$\sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k}{n} (H_n-H_k) \frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}  \frac{(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} 2^{n-1}}{n} \binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1}{2}}^{-1}$$

> Now I'm curious if there's a general closed form for this sum:
>
> $$f_n(x)=\sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k}{n} (H_n-H_k) x^k$$

**Important note:** there's a hypergeometric closed sum for this expression, because it originated from a hypergeometric function. So I am searching for elementary closed form (with polynomial, rational and maybe algebraic functions involved).

If we separate it in two parts, we have:

$$f_n (x) =(-1)^n H_n P_n (2x-1)-\sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k}{n} H_k x^k$$

Which means that the problem reduces to finding:

$$g_n(x)=\sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k}{n} H_k x^k$$

If we represent the harmonic numbers as integrals, we have:

> $$g_n(x)=(-1)^n\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{1-t} \left( P_n(2x-1)-P_n(2 x t-1) \right) $$

Now I guess we need to look up some integrals with Legendre polynomials.

Though this integral explains why $x=1/2$ is a special case.

---

One of the reasons for my curiosity is this identity for $x>1$:

$$\color{blue}{\log x =-2 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k}{n} (H_n-H_k) \frac{x^k}{(x-1)^k}}{(-1)^n  P_n \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1} \right)}}$$

The limit converges very fast, especially for large $x$.

Compare:

$$F(x,n)=-2 \frac{\sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k}{n} (H_n-H_k) \frac{x^k}{(x-1)^k}}{(-1)^n  P_n \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1} \right)}$$

$$G(x,n)= 2 \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1} \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right)^{2k+1}$$

The limit performs orders of magnitude better (though it's more difficult to evaluate for the same number of terms clearly).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to verify the first closed form case for even $n>0$.

Comment: @StevenClark, the signs are wrong, for even $n$ it should be $-H_n$

Comment: Could you please tell me the source of the $\log x$ identity in blue above?

Comment: @StevenClark, I derived it myself, there's no source

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a another look at this question and the linked question which I assume are related to the derivation.

Comment: @StevenClark, yes, the linked question is essentially answered by the identity in this post. I just wanted to know if there's a way to simplify the finite sum which doesn't involve the hypergeometric function from which it originated. Thank you for your useful comments!

Comment: I reviewed the linked question and the answer you posted there. I don't see anything wrong with the answer you posted there but I still don't understand the derivation of your identity for $\log(x)$. I know $\log (x)=(x-1) \, _2F_1(1,1;2;1-x)$, but I don't understand how you derived the infinite sum for $\log(x)$ as all of the formulas I  reviewed were finite sums.

Comment: Your identity for $\log(x)$ actually seems to be valid for $\Re(x)\ge 0\land x\ne 0\land x\ne 1$, but I noticed for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ it seems to converge better at integer values of $x$. The formula seems to exhibit a large divergence at non-integer values of $x$ as the evaluation limit of the sum is increased. I suspect this is due to the alternating sign of the terms of the sum combined with rounding errors, and this divergence can perhaps be eliminated by increasing the precision of the calculations as the evaluation limit of the sum increases.

Comment: Can i ask what sort of closed form you are expecting given that what you have is a polynomial?  for example does the trivial expression  ${{g}_{n}}\left( x \right)=\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{n}}}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\left| z \right|=r}^{{}}{\frac{\ln \left( 1-z \right)}{\left( z-1 \right)z}{{{\tilde{P}}}_{n}}\left( x{{z}^{-1}} \right)dz}$  count?

Comment: @mathstackuser12, frankly, I'm not sure what I was expecting. Maybe some further simplifications, but now I doubt it's possible

Comment: I have a Rodrigues style form for g if you're interested. And i should also add that i don't yet have a proof (i cheated and used mathematica to do a sum - remarkably it could calculate it!).  i can sketch out the ideas though.

Comment: Consider writing the function in the following form
${{g}_{n}}\left( x \right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{{}}\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}{{H}_{k}}}{\Gamma \left( k+1 \right)\Gamma \left( 1+n-k \right)}\frac{{{d}^{n}}}{d{{x}^{n}}}{{x}^{k+n}}$
Mathematica can do this summation.  It yields
${{g}_{n}}\left( x \right)=\frac{{{d}^{n}}}{d{{x}^{n}}}{{x}^{n}}\left\{ \frac{{{\left( 1-x \right)}^{n}}\left\{ {{H}_{n}}+\log \left( \frac{x}{\left( x-1 \right)} \right) \right\}}{\Gamma \left( 1+n \right)}-\frac{1}{\left( x-1 \right)}F\left[ 1,1+n;2+n;{{\left( 1-x \right)}^{-1}} \right] \right\}$